# Generating sequence of unique strings with the length of 7 or 8 characters

Tags: php, unique

It's so much nice to track a user file with a nice string like "JES9-99S" instead of file no 3992

Suppose at most we have 10MIL files, i need a uniqid generator algorithm that can generate unique id's with length of 7 or 8 characters.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why the '7 or 8' limitation? And what's wrong with a number (besides the limited range per byte in ascii)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify this to fit your needs:

- [Create short IDs with PHP - Like Youtube or TinyURL](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/)

Comment: `You may want to remove vouwels (a, e, o, u, i) from $index as to avoid combinations that result in: 'penis' or other dirty words that could get your customers upset.` lol